# VB6 mouse hook to capture a control a user clicks

Tags: vb6, setwindowshookex, mouse-hook

I have a keyboard hook that listens for [shift] + [F12] key button press to activate an edit mode in my program. By edit mode, I mean that any form that is inactive in the program window is disabled and focus is set to the active window. Furthermore, I alter the GUI to reflect that the user is running edit mode.

The purpose is of this all is to customize specific form controls that a user clicks on (e.g If they click on a label or combobox, a user would be able to edit the data that populates this information from a database). What I am really searching for is the ability to access the control name of the control that a user clicks on in the active form, DYNAMICALLY (without setting events on each form). Therefore, once a user clicks on a control such as a label, combo box, listview or listbox (on the active form), I would like to capture the control name clicked and pass that to another form that will handle the editing of this control.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go to the trouble of using the API for what you want to do.  All of the controls you mention expose a Click event.  (If the control you want to use doesn't have a Click event, it almost certainly has a MouseDown event which will work just as well.)  Just write a sub that takes the control as an argument and passes what info you want to the other form.  Then in each of the controls (you can use control arrays for controls of the same type), call this sub.  Something like this:

```
Sub DoTheWork(cCtl As Control)
    Form2.CallSomeMethod(cCtl) 'Passes a reference to the entire control 
    Form2.CallSomeOtherMethod(cCtl.Name) 'Just passes the name
End Sub

Sub Command1_Click()
    DoTheWork Command1
End Sub

Sub Label1_Click(Index As Integer) 'control array
    DoTheWork Label1(Index)
End Sub
```

Now, if you really want to get involved in using SetWindowsHookEx and all that, here's a bit of annotated code that you can use to figure it out.  This code allows you to change fonts on the MsgBox function, by substituting itself for any MsgBox call.  (FYI, Microsoft implemented "CBT hooking" to support computer-based training back in the day, hence the term.)

```
'This code allows font changes and various other format customizations of the standard VB6 MsgBox dialog box.  It
'uses CBT hooking to intercept an VB6-internal window call.  In this case, it intercepts a MsgBox call, then gets 
'a handle to the MsgBox window as well as its various child windows (the label containing the message text, any 
'buttons, and an icon if it exists).  It then resizes the window to accommodate the message text and other windows,
'and repositions the icon and any command buttons.  Finally, it positions the msgbox window in the center of the 
'screen.

'General Note: notes are above the line of code to which they apply.

Option Explicit

' Window size and position constants
Private Const ICON_WIDTH As Integer = 32
Private Const BTN_WIDTH As Integer = 75
Private Const BTN_HEIGHT As Integer = 23
Private Const BTN_SPACER As Integer = 6    ' Space between 2 buttons
Private Const STW_OFFSET As Integer = 12   ' Standard window offset, minimum distance one window can be from
                                           ' the edge of its container

' SendMessage constants that we will use
Private Const WM_SETFONT = &H30
Private Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD

' Necessary constants  for CBT hooking
Private Const HCBT_CREATEWND = 3
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const WH_CBT = 5

' Working variables that require module-wide scope
Private hHook As Long
Private myFont As IFont
Private cPrompt As String
Private hwndStatic As Long
Private ButtonHandles() As Long
Private xPixels As Long
Private yPixels As Long
Private isIcon As Boolean

' The API Type declarations we need
Private Type SIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
'GETTEXT needs a String argument for lParam, SETFONT needs an Any argument there, hence 2 declarations for SendMessageA
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageS Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long

' Wrapper for the normal MsgBox function
Public Function myMsgBox(Prompt As String, Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal fSize As Integer, ByVal fBold As Boolean, ByVal fItalic As Boolean, ByVal fULine As Boolean, fFaceName As String, Optional Title As String, Optional HelpFile As String, Optional Context As Long, Optional x As Long, Optional y As Long) As Long
'x and y arguments are optional and are in twips.  If not specified, msgbox will use default window sizes
'and positions, which work fine if you are using default font sizes.  If you aren't they may not.
cPrompt = Prompt
Set myFont = New StdFont
With myFont  ' We can make whatever adjustments we like here to the font
     .SIZE = fSize 
     .Bold = fBold
     .Italic = fItalic
     .Underline = fULine
     .Name = fFaceName
End With
'Convert x and y arguments to pixels from twips.  (Twips are the same size no matter what the screen resolution; pixels aren't.)
If Not IsMissing(x) Then
    xPixels = Int(x / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX)
End If
If Not IsMissing(y) Then
    yPixels = Int(y / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY)
End If
'Set up the hook to catch windows messages, call CBTProc when there is one
hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf CBTProc, App.hInstance, 0)
'This will call CBTProc, passing the handle of the MsgBox window to the wParam argument.
myMsgBox = MsgBox(Prompt, Buttons, Title, HelpFile, Context)
End Function

Private Function CBTProc(ByVal lMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim statX As Integer   'X dimension of static (text) window
Dim statY As Integer   'Y dimension of same
Dim cLeft As Integer   'Current Left value for current button, used to position buttons along x axis
Dim rc As RECT         'Used with GetClientRect
If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
    'Immediately unhook (we have the event we're looking for, and don't want to handle any more CBT events)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
    'Call EnumChildWindowProc once for each window that is contained in the MsgBox (each button and frame is a child window)
    EnumChildWindows wParam, AddressOf EnumChildWindowProc, 0
    'Reinitialize the static buttoncount variable, see the notes in the proc
    EnumChildWindowProc 0, 1
    'Should always be true, but this prevents an abend if for some reason we fail to get the text window
    If hwndStatic Then
        'If the x parameter has been supplied to the main wrapper, then xPixels <> 0
        If xPixels <> 0 Then
            With Screen
                'Center the MsgBox window in the screen
                SetWindowPos wParam, 0, (.Width / .TwipsPerPixelX - xPixels) / 2, _
                            (.Height / .TwipsPerPixelY - yPixels) / 2, xPixels, yPixels, 0
            End With
            'Analogous to the ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight properties.  Client rectangle's dimensions are
            'returned to the rc type and exclude the dimensions of the title bar and the borders.
            GetClientRect wParam, rc
            'Calculate x and y values for text window.  If there's an icon, we need to reduce the size of the
            'text window by the width of the icon plus a standard offset value.
            statX = rc.Right - rc.Left - STW_OFFSET * 2 - ((isIcon And 1) * (ICON_WIDTH + STW_OFFSET))
            statY = rc.Bottom - rc.Top - BTN_HEIGHT - STW_OFFSET * 2
            'We need to position the text window along the x axis such that it's a standard offset from the left
            'border of the msgbox, plus the width of the icon and another standard offset if the icon exists.
            SetWindowPos hwndStatic, 0, STW_OFFSET + (isIcon And 1) * (ICON_WIDTH + STW_OFFSET), STW_OFFSET, statX, statY, 0
            isIcon = 0
            'Loop through the button handles, calculating the left border position each time.
            For i = 0 To UBound(ButtonHandles)
                'Current left border is half the container window's width, less the width of half the total
                'number of buttons, plus the offset of the current button in the array.
                cLeft = Int(xPixels / 2 + BTN_WIDTH * (i - (UBound(ButtonHandles) + 1) / 2))
                'Modify the above to add button spacer widths.
                cLeft = cLeft + BTN_SPACER * (i - (UBound(ButtonHandles) - 1) + (UBound(ButtonHandles) Mod 2) / 2)
                'The Y value is 1 standard offset more than the height of the text window.
                SetWindowPos ButtonHandles(i), 0, cLeft, statY + STW_OFFSET, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT, 0
            Next
        End If
        SendMessage hwndStatic, WM_SETFONT, myFont.hFont, True
    End If
End If
CBTProc = 0 ' allow operation to continue
End Function

Private Function EnumChildWindowProc(ByVal hChild As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Static ButtonCount As Integer
Dim sLen As Integer
Dim wClass As String
Dim wText As String
Dim rc As RECT
If lParam Then
    ButtonCount = 0     'See the direct call of this proc in CBTProc: resets the ButtonCount variable to 0
    Exit Function
End If
wClass = String(64, 0)
'look up the type of the current window
sLen = GetClassName(hChild, wClass, 63)
wClass = Left(wClass, sLen)
'We have either one or two static windows: optionally the icon (the first window if it's there) and the
'text window (analogous to a label control).
If wClass = "Static" Then
    'If we already have the text window's handle, we don't need to do this anymore.
    If Not hwndStatic Then
        'Find out if the current window's text value is the same as the text passed in to the cPrompt
        'argument in the main wrapper function.  If it is, it's the text window and we store the handle
        'value in hwndStatic.  If it isn't, then it's an icon and we set the isIcon flag.
        wText = String(Len(cPrompt) + 1, 0)
        sLen = SendMessageS(hChild, WM_GETTEXT, 255, wText)
        wText = Left(wText, sLen)
        If wText = cPrompt Then
            hwndStatic = hChild
        Else
            isIcon = True
        End If
    End If
ElseIf wClass = "Button" Then
    'Store the button's handle in the ButtonHandles array
    ReDim Preserve ButtonHandles(ButtonCount)
    ButtonHandles(ButtonCount) = hChild
    ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
End If
EnumChildWindowProc = 1  ' Continue enumeration
End Function
```

Comment: I need to do this dynamically. The goal is to be able to edit any form without having to create event procedures for each (I have a form to handle the edit which will have the control name of the control a user has clicked on passed to it).

Comment: Then you need to look at dynamic controls.  The way that VB6 does this is a bit of a kludge, but it works.  Put one of each dynamic control on the form.  Make it invisible, and set its index property to 0.  Then use the ~Load~ statement to add new controls as needed.  (The first control to add, you'd make the existing control visible; then use ~Load~ for subsequent controls.)  [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241103(v=vs.60).aspx) some doc on how to do this.

Comment: Control arrays don't allow to listen to event of the individual controls in the array. You can impl `Click` w/ parameter `Index` on the control array instance only. If you try to use `Dim ... WithEvents` on an element of the control array, assignment fails.

Comment: @wqw That's true, but I don't see where the OP is saying that he needs to implement a custom event on the controls.  He only needs to use the Click event, so the Index argument will work for him.  (Am I wrong?)